# pagecreate event causes javascript error - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery mobile for the first time and am getting an error on my first attempt at handing the pagecreate event.

```
$('body').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

Shows this error in Chrome (similar error on iPad):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method     'type'
i.parseUrljquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js:45
bjquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js:51
(anonymous function)
```

The same error occurs if I try using any other selector, such as my #container div. I'm sure I'm doing something fairly basic wrong here, any advice appreciated!

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: Here's an example of the error happening:

http://www.markdavies.com.au/staging/test/jqmobile/

Comment: Looks as though my problem was the minimum jquery version. Changed that line to use jquery 1.6.1 and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This page helped me a lot: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're binding to the body tag and need to bind to a page id. More in the docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html

You have

```
$('body').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

Should be

```
$('#pageId').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    alert('hello world');
});
```